# Pagination not working in search

Tags: search, pagination

Pagination is not working in my search result page.
Below is my code.
can anyone correct this??

```
{exp:search:search_results backspace="5" limit="2" paginate="both"}

    {title}<br/>
    {excerpt}

    {paginate}
        <p>
            Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}
        </p>
    {/paginate}

{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Comment: Could you **please** start using markdown and code blocks in your questions?

Comment: Do you have more than two results with a status of open?